# Как исправить данный баг, при сохранений данных в файл в конце добавляется пустая строка NodeJS модуль fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

```
const arr = ['Яблоко', 'Груша', 'Апельсин'];
let str = '';
arr.forEach(item => {
  str += `${item}\r\n`;
  fs.writeFileSync('data.txt', arr);
});
```

В результате получаю

```
Яблоко
Груша
Апельсин
```

Comment: ты же сам каждый раз добавляешь `\r\n` - переход на новую строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто сделайте объединение данных с нужным разделителем и сохраните в файл

```js
const arr = ['Яблоко', 'Груша', 'Апельсин'];

console.log(arr.join("\r\n"))

fs.writeFileSync('data.txt', arr.join("\r\n"));
```